# ggplot for loop outputs all the same graph

Tags: r, ggplot2

I've written a for loop which goes through the columns of a dataframe and produces a graph for each column using ggplot. The problem is the graphs that are output are all the same - they're all graphs of the final column.

The code I've used is:

```
library(gridExtra)
library(ggplot2)
test1 <- c("Person1","Person2","Person3","Person4","Person5")
test2 <- as.data.frame(c(1,2,3,4,5))
test3 <- as.data.frame(c(2,2,2,2,2))
test4 <- as.data.frame(c(1,3,5,3,1))
test5 <- as.data.frame(c(5,4,3,2,1))
test <- cbind(test1,test2,test3,test4,test5)
rm(test1,test2,test3,test4,test5)
colnames(test) <- c("Person","var1","var2","var3","var4")

for(i in 2:5){
  nam <- paste0("graph", i-1)
  graph_temp <- ggplot(test, aes(Person, test[,i])) + geom_bar(stat = "identity")
  assign(nam, graph_temp)
}
grid.arrange(graph1, graph2, graph3, graph4, ncol=2)
```

What I'm aiming for is the plot from this code:

```
library(gridExtra)
library(ggplot2)
test1 <- c("Person1","Person2","Person3","Person4","Person5")
test2 <- as.data.frame(c(1,2,3,4,5))
test3 <- as.data.frame(c(2,2,2,2,2))
test4 <- as.data.frame(c(1,3,5,3,1))
test5 <- as.data.frame(c(5,4,3,2,1))
test <- cbind(test1,test2,test3,test4,test5)
rm(test1,test2,test3,test4,test5)
colnames(test) <- c("Person","var1","var2","var3","var4")

graph1 <- ggplot(test, aes(Person, test[,2])) + geom_bar(stat = "identity")
graph2 <- ggplot(test, aes(Person, test[,3])) + geom_bar(stat = "identity")
graph3 <- ggplot(test, aes(Person, test[,4])) + geom_bar(stat = "identity")
graph4 <- ggplot(test, aes(Person, test[,5])) + geom_bar(stat = "identity")
grid.arrange(graph1, graph2, graph3, graph4, ncol=2)
```

I know there's a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26034177/r-saving-multiple-ggplots-using-a-for-loop) on saving ggplots in a for loop, but I've not managed to get that one to work for this problem.

Comment: You are overwriting `graph_temp` and so only the last one gets plotted. Learn to use lists. If you can you should avoid for-loops, although `lapply` is just a for-loop in disguise. At least it protects you from this typical newbie-error.

Comment: Thanks, although are you `graph_temp` was the problem? I thought it wrote it out to another object in each iteration of the for loop (e.g. `graph_temp` to `graph1`, `graph_temp` to `graph2`, etc.). Also, just for future reference, on a site which is about building a communities' skills, statements like 'learn to use lists' with no elaboration and 'typical newbie-error' aren't overly helpful. I refer you to your peer's answer below for the same things said in a constructive manner. I think this is a general issue on Stack Overflow, relative 'newbies' can be scared into not asking questions.

Comment: You need to understand lazy evaluation. It wasn't a problem with that function but rather a problem with using a for-loop. We were all newbies once. The answer you preferred did not explain the cause of your error nor give you advice about what strategy to use in the future.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a more concise way to produce your example:

```
df <- data.frame(
  Person = paste0("Person", 1:5),
  var1 = c(1,2,3,4,5),
  var2 = c(2,2,2,2,2),
  var3 = c(1,3,5,3,1),
  var4 = c(5,4,3,2,1)
)
```

Now, about your plots.

## Best solution

Reshape the data frame to 'long' format, and then use facets:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyr)
gather(df, var, value, -Person) %>%
  ggplot(aes(Person, value)) +
    geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
    facet_wrap(~ var)
```

[image]

## Otherwise…

If you gotta stick with a data structure that looks like what you posted, then use [`aes_string`](http://docs.ggplot2.org/0.9.3/aes_string.html):

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)

g <- lapply(1:4, function(i) {

  ggplot(df, aes_string("Person", paste0("var", i))) +
    geom_bar(stat = "identity")

})
grid.arrange(grobs = g, ncol = 2)
```

[image]