# Repeated plotting of ggplots in R

Tags: r, for-loop, ggplot2, dplyr, tidyr

This question has been asked before, but not in a way it fits my data, so I try again :)

I want to make multiple individual ggplots without having to specify how it should be made every time. 
My dataset contains gene expression data and from these I want to plot specific genes.

Let's use this as an example

```
df <- read.table(header = TRUE, 
                   stringsAsFactors = FALSE, 
                   text="GENE   SYMBOL          Patient1   Patient2   
                   TP53         ILMN_2            3.55        3.66
                   TP53         ILMN_3            5.49        4.99
                   XBP1         ILMN_5            4.06        2.53
                   TP27         ILMN_1            2.53        3.33
                   REDD1        ILMN_4            3.99        4.56
                   ERO1L        ILMN_6            5.02        6.95
                   STK11        ILMN_9            3.64        2.01
                   HIF2A        ILMN_8            2.96        4.76 ")
```

In order to plot selected genes from `df`, I usually do the following:

First I make an object I can use for searching in the dataframe

```
SYMBOL_info <- select(df, SYMBOL)
```

Then, I define the gene I'm interested in as:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)

geneOfInterest <- c(SYMBOL_info == "5")
```

Next, the gene of interest is found in the dataframe and the dataframe is gathered to fit ggplots requirements:

```
df_gather<- df %>%
  filter(geneOfInterest) %>% 
  gather(key=Patient, value=values, -c(GENE, SYMBOL))
```

In the end, the gene of interest in the dataset is plotted:

```
ggplot()+
  geom_point(df_gather, mapping = aes(x=Patient, y=values, color=GENE))+
  labs(title="XBP1 plot", subtitle = "Symbol: 5")+
  ggsave("XBP1_plot.png")
```

However, I have many genes I'd like to plot, e.g. both versions of TP53, REDD1, STK11 and HIF1A. Any suggestions to how this can be done without having to change `geneOfInterest` and the information with in the plotting-part of the code everytime? I guess a for loop needs to be made, but copying the other solutions given here didn't help me (as shown here: [R: saving multiple ggplots using a for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26034177/r-saving-multiple-ggplots-using-a-for-loop)).

Thanks in advance! :)

EDIT: SYMBOL-values are changed to start with ILMN_ instead of just numbers

Comment: I'd avoid the loop and write a little function instead. Also I get an error: `object 'PROBE_ID' not found`

Comment: This worked for me using facets 
         new.df <- melt(df %>% select(-SYMBOL))
        ggplot(new.df) + geom_point(aes(x = variable, y = value, color = Gene)) + facet_wrap( ~ Gene)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on the number of genes and data you want to plot, I recommend to plot everything in one plot using facets like this:

```
df %>% 
  filter(Gene %in% c("TP53", "ERO1L", "HIF2A")) %>% 
  gather(key, value, -Gene, -SYMBOL) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(key, value, fill=Gene))+
    geom_col()+
    facet_wrap(~Gene+ SYMBOL, labeller = label_both)
```

[image]

Otherwise try this:

```
sapply(c(2,3,9), function(x){
  geneOfInterest <- df[ df$SYMBOL == x, 1]
  df %>%
   filter(SYMBOL == x) %>% 
   gather(key=Patient, value=values, -Gene,-SYMBOL) %>% 
   ggplot(aes(x=Patient, y=values, color=Gene))+
    geom_point()+
    labs(title="XBP1 plot", subtitle = "Symbol: 5") + 
    ggsave(paste0(geneOfInterest, "_plot.png"))
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, Jimbou!

I just want to add that I changed your suggested function into this (to include the Gene and Symbol in both the plot and file-name):

```
sapply(c(2,5,9), function(x){
  geneOfInterest <- df[ df$SYMBOL == x, 1]
  df %>%
    filter(SYMBOL == x) %>% 
    gather(key=Patient, value=values, -GENE,-SYMBOL) %>% 
    ggplot(aes(x=Patient, y=values, color=GENE))+
    geom_point()+
    labs(title=paste0(symbolOfInterest, " plot"), subtitle =paste0("Symbol: ", x)) + 
    ggsave(paste0(geneOfInterest,"_symbol_",x, "_plot.png"))
})
```