# Combine multiple plot in loop color each plot by different column in dataframe

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying combine the multiple plots according to on of the [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26034177/save-multiple-ggplots-using-a-for-loop) here my problem is I want to separate based on coloured plot with different values can any one help me what I am missing, (Note: my original data i have some 30 column values)

```
data(iris)
list_data=c("Petal.Length", "Petal.Width")
# Make plots.
plot_list = list()
for (i in list_data) {
  p = ggplot(iris, aes(y=Sepal.Length, x=Sepal.Width)) +
    geom_point(size=3, aes(colour=i))
  plot_list[[i]] = p
}

pdf("plots.pdf")
for (i in list_data) {
  print(plot_list[[i]])
}

dev.off()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We may use `.data[[i]]` in `colour`

```
for (i in list_data) {
  p = ggplot(iris, aes(y=Sepal.Length, x=Sepal.Width)) +
    geom_point(size=3, aes(colour=.data[[i]]))
  plot_list[[i]] = p
}
```

-output

```
> plot_list[[1]]
```

[image]